# How do I perform name standardization in nifi using update record processor?

Tags: apache-nifi, title-case

In my nifi flow, I need to perform name standardization for a specific column.
Examples include:

1. Making name title case
2. If it contain mc before something such as donald, make it McDonald
   and such other things.

How do I perform all of these in a single go in update record processor?
Also, I dont see any function for making name titlecase in nifi expression language. I only see upper and lower. How do i build the logic? Do I need to make a custom property for this?
Please let me know. thanks.

Comment: I think if you have a lot of custom logic to implement, then try `ExecuteScript`.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with the method [WordUtils.capitalizeFully](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully-java.lang.String-). Check also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661748/java-is-there-a-better-substitute-for-wordutils-capitalizefully-using-strings)

**ScriptedTransformRecord** processor:

- `Record Reader`: `JsonTreeReader`
- `Record Writer`: `JsonRecordSetWriter`
- `Script Language`: `Groovy`
- `Script Body`:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils

record.setValue("text", WordUtils.capitalizeFully(record.getValue("text")))
record
```

**Example**

***input json***

```json
[
  {
    "text": "man OF stEEL"
  },
  {
    "text": "hELLo"
  }
]
```

***output json***

```json
[
  {
    "text": "Man Of Steel"
  },
  {
    "text": "Hello"
  }
]
```